# contacts do not sync and get overriden/deleted

Tags: contacts, 7.0-nougat, oneplus-3

When I use the built-in contact app with either a outlook.com or a office365 account on the phone created contacts get deleted after some time and they don't sync to the web.

What have I done:

- delete and add account
- factory reset

Similiar to https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/contacts-keep-deleating.484478/ except that I already save to another account.

Comment: what phone are you using? What is the OS version?

Comment: See tagged, op3 with newest nougat update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to stop the outlook App overriding/deleting created contacts. But syncing contacts via gmail, but using the Outlook App for everything else seems to work.

- Disable Contact syncing for all accounts added to the Outlook App in the system settings.
- Add all accounts to as an exchange account to the google App (In Account settings, there should be an 'Exchange' option. Disable all syncing but contact sycning.

  - For outlook.com accounts you will need to manually select 'Exchange' in the next step, even after selecting Exchange Account in Account Settings (else it defaults to IMAP).

Comment: I will accept this answer, if there is no better solution posted, after the bounty expires.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here on the Moto G5 Plus.  My answer was simply to avoid the Outlook app and force myself to get comfortable with Google's Mail app.  By not having Outlook installed, the exchange contacts from my Office 365 Personal account are working fine now.  As stated above, you must do manual setup to have the account recognized as an Exchange account rather than an IMAP.
Aside from the contacts challenge, Outlook was not allowing me to add the gmail account to the app (maybe a Google rescriction?), so in the end avoiding Outlook solved both problems.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not a user of OnePlus, but I can say Outlook App in Android has
>   some issues built-in for quite a long time, so one suggestion is that:
>   uninstall the app & make a fresh install again. Hope it helps.

Comment: 'factory reset' did include a fresh install